# Поиск файлов в linux по времени доступу к ним

Tags: linux, файлы, bash, terminal

Как вывести первые  5 файлов каталога, к которым был недавно осуществлен доступ в каталоге /etc?

Comment: `ls -1t /etc | head -5`

Comment: @0xdb, `-t` — это *modification time*. а `-u` — это требуемое *access time*. // strike92, обновление *access time* нередко отключают (опция `noatime` при монтировании ф.с.). в таком случае возвращаемое значение не соответствует истине.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, уже давно используют *relatime*. Но все эти игры со временем последнего доступа сильно зависят от конкретной ФС, дистрибутива (параметров конфигурации) и  версии ядра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«время доступа» (*access time*) для файла/каталога означает либо время последнего получения его содержимого, либо изменения этого содержимого (что произошло позднее).

получить список файлов/каталогов (внутри указанного), отсортированных в обратном порядке (начиная с тех, доступ к которым был позднее) можно с помощью опции `-u` программы *ls*:

```
$ ls -u каталог
```

отобрать из выданных строк только первые пять можно, например, программой *head*:

```
$ ls -u каталог | head -n 5
```

---

довольно часто файловые системы монтируют с опцией `noatime` (уточните в выводе программы *mount*). в этом случае *access time* не будет соответствовать истине.

возможно, в такой ситуации подойдёт «время модификации» (*modification time*), которое обновляется только при изменении содержимого файла/каталога (для каталога это означает — был создан/удалён/переименован/модифицирован находящийся в нём файл/каталог).

получить список файлов/каталогов (внутри указанного), отсортированных в обратном порядке (начиная с тех, которые были изменены позднее) можно с помощью опции `-t` программы *ls*:

```
$ ls -t каталог
```

отобрать из выданных строк только первые пять можно, например, программой *head*:

```
$ ls -t каталог | head -n 5
```

---

изменить порядок вывода на противоположный (в обоих случаях) можно, добавив опцию `-r`:

```
$ ls -ur каталог
$ ls -tr каталог
```